# json_decode variables php

Tags: php, json, parsing

I'm simply trying to extract variables from a json_decode

the resulting decoded code (a snippet of) is:

```
auth_info:
array(4) {
["profile"]=>
  array(13) {
  ["name"]=>
  array(3) {
  ["givenName"]=>
  string(6) "John"
  ["familyName"]=>
  string(7) "Doe"
  ["formatted"]=>
  string(14) "John Doe"
  }
 }
}
```

I'm trying all things such as:

```
echo "\n\nMy name is ".$auth_info['profile']->name->givenName;
```

But all to no avail..ideas please?

Many thanks as always

Darren

Comment: You should be using `print_r`, not `var_dump`, to see the structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are all arrays, try this.

```
$auth_info['profile']['name']['givenName']
```

Comment: Thank you so much - it won't let me accept this answer yet which is a bit sill but spot on...appreciated.